# Is I2S or USB the most direct link to my DAC's processor?

Tags: usb, i2s

I’m building my first streamer and I’m trying to determine the most direct route ( the least amount of conversion) to my DAC. I use a Denafrips Terminator II DAC. Would a USB signal be converted to I2S once it gets to the Denafrips? If that’s the case, I will choose a PCIe card that sends I2S instead of USB. Basically what is my DAC’s internal language? Does it use I2S?

Comment: Why are you looking to minimize conversions, from the standpoint of **observable** signal differences at the output of your *DAC? USB and I2S are both digital formats, so your "conversion" is just reframing bits from one packet format to another, whether it's CPU movs to PCIe transactions, PCIe to USB, USB to I2S, or I2S to the wires in the DAC linking the I2S decoder to the actual DAC core. Bits don't become "noisy" in the way that analog signals going through a real-world analog device do.

Comment: You should ask the manufacturer. The information is not in any published literature that I have found. There may be a difference in time delay for the various inputs.

Comment: Electrically, I2S. USB is pretty indirect and generally involves buffering. But I2S is generally meant to run across a PCB, not across cables. See AES/EBU or SP-DIF for that.

Answer (score 4):

The DAC is controlled by an FPGA, and there's no loss between the digital inputs, so there's nothing more "direct" about one vs. the other. USB necessarily adds a delay that's not present in other interface methods. That's about it.

From [their product page](https://www.denafrips.com/terminator):

> State of the art fourth generation discrete resistor 26Bit R-2R [...] a total breakthrough of the traditional integrated chip constraints.

It takes some hubris to claim that a bunch of SMD resistors on a PCB will behave better than thermally balanced structures on an IC, with orders of magnitude better thermal coupling, etc... But as far as Rube Goldberg schemes go, theirs gets top marks for overkill. My kind of a thing - a beautifully, unnecessarily, overengineered design :)

Comment: All those evil electrolytic caps - talk about muddying the water…..

Answer (score 2):

Internally the DAC uses I2S. From a quick read of the datasheet, this DAC also supports AES, SPDIF and I2S, which are isochronous interfaces running at the sample rate. It also supports USB, which would consume data at an average of the isochronous rate determined by the DAC master clock.

This DAC also supports an external clock. This allows making its playback rate the same as other devices in your system. The isochronous interfaces (AES, SPDIF and I2S) also need to be sharing that same clock. In contrast, USB will adapt to it, and the PC would supply data at the average rate.

As for performance, they should all be the same - there’s no benefit to using one digital interface over the other as they’re, well, digital. What matters is the jitter on the master clock being fed to the DAC.

So for just this one DAC you can select its internal master clock, then use USB from your host and it will work just fine.

Multiple DACs would benefit from using AES or SPDIF and an external master clock; delay would be very small (~1 sample) and constant.

I would not bother with direct I2S in. In fact I think it would cause more inter-box system noise in the box than the others since it’s unbalanced digital and has a larger voltage swing than the other choices.

Comment: USB should have higher latency.

Comment: It has FIFO reclocking so latency will be random anyway

Comment: Not random, but distributed around an average depending on the host driver behavior. That said, USB latency compared to the sample rate is probably very small.

Comment: Mainly it’s about what happens at startup. If you are launching multiple USB streams at once, what would be delay of each? If done carefully using DMA the delay variation would be very small.

Comment: The dac manufacturer just got back to me. This is their answer: “ I2S pcie is your best bet, the digital signals will be sent directly to the FPGA for processing.” The pcie card I’ve selected is a Pink Faun I2S bridge card. Supposedly it will send an I2S signal directly to the dac, resulting in less delay, buffer, latency, “conversion.”

Comment: That's a silly answer on their part. All the interfaces are digital, so the stream results will be the same. There is no 'loss' going from AES -> I2S or USB -> I2S, the data are bit-for-bit identical. Yes, there will be some delay on USB, but it will be small, and if you're only running the one DAC it does not matter.